# React Router - how to constrain params in route matching?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I don't really get how to constrain params with, for example a regex.
How to differentiate these two routes?

```
  <Router>
    <Route path="/:alpha_index" component={Child1} />
    <Route path="/:numeric_index" component={Child2} />
  </Router>
```

And prevent "/123" from firing the first route?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

React-router v4 now allows you to use regexes to match params -- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string

```
const NumberRoute = () => <div>Number Route</div>;
const StringRoute = () => <div>String Route</div>;

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/foo/:id(\\d+)" component={NumberRoute}/>
        <Route exact path="/foo/:path(\\w+)" component={StringRoute}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

More info:
https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters

Comment: Note the swapping the Route order will break the logic, (\w+) will match BOTH digits and strings. a Safer regex may be ([a-z]+) as this will not match digits ever.

Comment: expression is missing \
`<Route exact path="/foo/:id(\\d+)" component={NumberRoute}/>`
refer [here](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters)

Comment: @Sean D. Do you know how to do this in v3?

Comment: For me, it only worked if I remove the extra "\", so `path="/foo/:id(\d+)"`

Comment: what's about the last version?

Comment: for V6 of react router this does not work any more. See https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/faq#what-happened-to-regexp-routes-paths

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if this is possible with React router at the moment. However there's a simple solution to your problem. Just do the int/alpha check in another component, like this:

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/:index" component={Child0} />
</Router>

const Child0 = (props) => {
    let n = props.params.index;
    if (!isNumeric(n)) {
        return <Child1 />;
    } else {
        return <Child2 />;
    }
}
```

* Note that the code above does not run, it's just there to show what I mean.