# React routing causes inexplicable behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Below is one of my routes

```
{
     path: "/news/:id",
     component: NewsDetail,
},
```

Below is the render code for `NewsDetail`

```
render() {
        console.log("id: ", this.props.match);
        if (isNaN(this.props.match.params.id)) {
            return <div/>;
        }
        return (
                <main className="news-detail">
                    <NewsInDetailSection news={initialsData.newsItems[this.props.match.params.id]} />
                </main>
                );
    }
```

Output of console.log is:

```
    id:  { path: '/news/:id',
  url: '/news/1529825022511',
  isExact: true,
  params: { id: '1529825022511' } }

   id:  { path: '/news/:id',
  url: '/news/vendors~app.bundle.js',
  isExact: true,
  params: { id: 'vendors~app.bundle.js' } }

  id:  { path: '/news/:id',
  url: '/news/app.bundle.js',
  isExact: true,
  params: { id: 'app.bundle.js' } }
```

> First log is fine, but I don't understand why app.bundle.js is getting
>   placed here. To deal with this I've added a patch using if condition
>   in my code, but this is not proper resolution it's just a workaround.
>
> I know I've written the question very badly, but I'm new to react and
>   I don't know how to explain this problem. Any response would be
>   appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any restrictions on what can be the `id` parameter. It can be anything. Hence it is also `app.bundle.js`. I don't exactly understand what the problem is if the URL matches `app.bundle.js` as that is a valid URL (technically speaking. Logically it's not true). Assuming you want to match only digits,

You need to add a **regex** to match only digits if your `news_id` has only digits. Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269736/react-router-how-to-constrain-params-in-route-matching).

Comment: app.bundle.js is not supposed to be called this way, React is doing this itself, I believe due to some bug in my code

Comment: Can you please post your package.json, webpack config and the project structure?